# java: Arrays.sort() with lambda expression

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda, java-8

I want to sort String elements in the array `months` by length using `Arrays.sort` method. I was told [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), that it's possible to use lambda expressions instead of creating new class implementing Comparator. Did it exactly the same way, yet it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String[] months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","December"};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(months)); //printing before


    //neither this works:
    Arrays.sort(months, 
            (a, b) -> Integer.signum(a.length() - b.length())   
    );

    //nor this:
    Arrays.sort(months, 
            (String a, String b) -> { return Integer.signum(a.length() - b.length()) }; 
    );


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(months)); //printing after
}
}
```

Comment: _"Did it exactly the same way, yet it doesn't work."_ No you didn't, read carefully what they did. You have syntax errors.

Comment: @ZouZou Perhaps he did. I don't think the OP is even using Java 8.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The cleanest way would be:

```
Arrays.sort(months, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

or, with a static import:

```
Arrays.sort(months, comparingInt(String::length));
```

---

However, this would work too but is more verbose:

```
Arrays.sort(months,
            (String a, String b) -> a.length() - b.length());
```

Or shorter:

```
Arrays.sort(months, (a, b) -> a.length() - b.length());
```

---

Finally your last one:

```
Arrays.sort(months, 
    (String a, String b) -> { return Integer.signum(a.length() - b.length()) }; 
);
```

has the `;` misplaced - it should be:

```
Arrays.sort(months, 
    (String a, String b) -> { return Integer.signum(a.length() - b.length()); }
);
```

Comment: +1 for showing `Comparator.comparing`, it is so much easier to grasp than writing a custom lambda or `Comparator`.

Comment: Well, that's helpful, but I'd like to know what's wrong with my solution.

Comment: @lavsprat I have added something showing your syntax error.

Comment: I suggest using `Integer.compare` instead of signum of `-`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Indeed - `signum(a-b)` has the risk of overflowing (even if it's unlikely for strings).

Comment: @lavsprat Then you don't have java 8 installed or you are not compiling with the right JDK or your IDE does not support it or you have a very old version or...

Comment: Oracle site says "You have the recommended Java installed (Version 7 Update 51).".

Comment: @lavsprat huh.... Version 7 != Version 8... Java 8 is here: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: I don't think `-` can overflow in this case, as both values are non-negative.

Comment: `Integer.signum` is obsolete. Just returning `a-b` (for these special `a` and `b` where `a-b` cannot overflow, of course) is enough. There is no need to set the absolute value to `1`. So wrapping a value which has the right sign already with an `Integer.signum(…)` call makes no sense for a `Comparator`.

Comment: I certainly prefer `Comparator.comparingInt()` over `comparing()` when what you are comparing are indeed `int`s. It’s clearer (and also avoids unnecessary boxing).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for this:

```
Arrays.sort(months, (a, b) -> Integer.signum(a.length() - b.length()));
```

Comment: Works for me... Are you sure you're using Java 8? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @lavsprat It also works for me, it prints `[May, June, July, March, April, August, January, October, February, December, September]`... What Java 8 version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse.
[This](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre) site says I have Version 7 Update 51.

Comment: Well of course you can't use lambdas then, as they are only available in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are looking for is in Java 8, which has not yet been released. It is scheduled for release in a few months if you want to wait, or if not beta downloads are available.

Comment: Useful comment, but not an answer.

Comment: @TedHopp It is an answer. His code isn't compiling because he's trying to use a Java 8 feature in Java 7!

Comment: His code isn't compiling because it has a syntax error (semicolon at the end of the second argument to `Arrays.sort`).

Comment: This comment is a bit misleading, unless you count three weeks as being "a few months": ship date is March 18th

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Arrays.sort(months, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```

Comment: Note that `Integer#compare` doesn't state it, but the return value is always `-1`, `0`, or `1` (whereas the javadoc implies it's merely `<0` or `>0`, so it is subject to change). `#signum` explicitly states this relationship. Either way, for `Arrays#sort`, I don't see what this answer contributes that the others didn't already cover 9 years ago.