# Sorting array in descending order in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was trying to sort an array called efficiency in descending order just like this:

```
Arrays.sort(efficiency, (a, b) -> b - a)
```

However, it throws an exception that no suitable method has been found.
I then check the Documentation and found that there actually is the method

```
    sort​(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Can you please post more details like, how your array 'efficiency' is initialized ? what type of elements does the array hold ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array has a non-primitive datatype, you could use the following:

`Arrays.sort(efficiency, Collections.reverseOrder());`

For a lambda specific approach I would check out this detailed answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970805/10171575