# What is the second argument doing in this function?

Tags: java

```
Arrays.sort(courses, (a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b - a);
```

I tried looking at the docs but cannot understand what the second argument is responsible for. I know that .sort(array, 1, 4) means sort from index 1 to 3. But in this case, the arrow with `-> a[1] - b[1]` and `((a, b) -> b - a)` is what I am unable to understand.

Comment: Read about lambda notations in java. then it will make sense.

Comment: What is ```courses```?

Comment: You can review this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970805/7357959

Comment: @AddeusExMachina "courses" is the actual list that has to be sorted

Comment: @sdfesvrtae4t4fw4efawef, you should try to understand the parameters of sort function in java, lambda notations.Then it will be very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow represents a [lambda function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that compares any two arguments `a` and `b`. Before lambdas were introduced (in Java 8), the sort would look like this:

```
Arrays.sort(courses, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }
});
```

I'm taking a guess at the type of `a` but feel free to substitute `int[]` with any numeric array.